# What is printed when this function is executed?

Tags: computer-science

I have some practice problems for a CS training test. Can you explain how to get to the right answer?

I am not sure what programming language is this but I try to convert these problems to python to make sense of what these mean. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rqnh.png)

here is my attempt in python to solve this but it doesn't seem that I got the right code as I don't get the values.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvNYF.png)

Comment: You should include all relevant text in the question. You should not like to images containing code.

Comment: This looks like _Can you do my homework for me_ kind of question, We are not here to work for you. If you need help with a probleme, please state your probleme and your tries. And if you can add some code. it's way easier than image.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
if n >= 0:
```

where you should have written

```
if n >= 4:
```

Also, the point here is that the function recursively calling itself. Instead of

```
return n/2
```

you need just

```
f(n/2)
```

Otherwise, you `return` before the print, which is not what the original code does.

Finally, a walkthrough. So you start at `f(16)`, and since 16 is greater than 4, it calls `f(16/2)`, and within, since 8 is greater than 4, it calls `f(8/2)`, and thin, since 4 is greater than *or equal to* 4, one last time it calls `f(4/2)`, within which it finally gets to the first `print` statement ever, printing `2`, then stepping back to the parent function, printing `4`, and so on, until it prints `16` and finishes.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now python prints just 2.0 Is there a way to make python print all the values in the function?( 2,4,8,16)